# why Aspx pages session gets expired repetedly for a .net application?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, session

I am working in a .Net chat application, in my chat room page session is getting expired repeatedly for small time period. I used 
`sessionState timeout="540"`  and `httpRuntime executionTimeout="999999"` `maxRequestLength="200000000" requestValidationmode="2.0"`
 in web.config file. but it is working. My page required continuous update because it is a chat page. but after some time it gets timed out and we need to re lode the page to get new messages. a interval is running in this page. any Idea is appreciable.

Comment: Enable logging and check if your application has not beed restarted. I had the same problem, when I was saving some data into `bin` folder. Modifying a `bin` folder results in application restart, which clears session and temporary data out.

Comment: Hi Yelder, I am new in .net so can you tell me how to Enable logging and I have restarted application more than one time.

Comment: If it works for some time as you mentionted in comment to someone's answer, then the problem is, probably, not in restarting. Can you show some other code and config?

Answer (score 0):

It makes no sense. When you still send requests to the server within the limited timeout, the session won't expire. For example, if you set the session timeout 5 minutes, then you request to the server each 1 minutes, the page won't expire because the client is still interacting with the server.

Comment: But it is happening. I used sessionState timeout="540" but after some time session gets expired. How to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using full or absolute url in any of your request? Change it to relative uri. e.g. `../home.aspx`